# If a JS script is cached, it there extra overhead in requesting it in a file that doesn't use it?

Tags: caching, request

Basically I want to keep all the `<link>` and `<script>` requests in one php file, but some scripts only pertain to one page on the site. I don't want to create extra overhead requesting a script that isn't used on a page.

However, extra scripts are all on the home page. So for first-timers to the site, they would generally come through the home page. AFAIK, the script is then cached.

Would this offset the overhead problem I mentioned? i.e. if the file is cached, is there no noticeable overhead from requesting it on another page?

Comment: you will get some good answers, but from what I know even if your scripts are not cached it's good to stick with having all of your script/link at the same place for sake of consistency unless they are significantly large.

Comment: Most browsers will still request the page/script again, and if the server replies with a `304 not modified`, they'll simply used the cached copy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they will be cached.

However, an HTTP header request to check for a newer file will still be sent on every subsequent page request. The response from your server will be "You have the newest version already". So it will use the one from the cache.

I find that HTTP requests are the great time killers of the web - especially for mobile devices, so at the very least you should use Expires header so that when you give the files to the browser you can say "*Don't request this file again for 30 days", etc.

Lastly, you can "prefetch" extra assets after page load so that it doesn't effect the user load time but still caches things while the user is on your home page.

* As a caveat, if you do use Expires header you will then need to do versioning through folder path or query parameter because web browsers will no longer check for new files. Something like this:

`<script src="http://yoursite.com/js/compressed_files.js?v=1"></script>`